# How to terminate the last action when a new label is clicked?

Tags: vb.net, colors, label

I have many labels. When a label is clicked, I change the `BackColor` to aqua. When I click on another label, both of them are aqua, but I want the color of the first label to go back to normal. It there a way to do that?

Here is my code:

```
Dim clickedLabel = TryCast(sender, Label)
If clickedLabel IsNot Nothing Then
    clickedLabel.BackColor = Color.Aqua
    TextBox1.Text = clickedLabel.Text
Else
End If
```

Comment: create a variable of type label at the module/class level, and populate it with the currently selected label. on click, set label referenced by variable back, set current label to new color, set tracking variable to currently clicked label.

Comment: I still don't get it, can you show me the code instead? Thank you so much.

Comment: The posted answer is also a good one. You should try it.

Answer (score 1):

Put them all in a collection so that you can apply the default-color on all others or - if they are all in the same container-control like a `Panel` - use this code:

```
For Each lbl In LabelPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Label)() 
    clickedLabel.BackColor = If(lbl Is clickedLabel, Color.Aqua, DefaultColor)
Next
TextBox1.Text = clickedLabel.Text
```

Instead of `LabelPanel.Controls` you could also use `Me.Controls`, but then all labels on the form are used even if it's not related. Labels that are in other container controls won't be find in this way anyway, so no recursive search.

`DefaultColor` is a `System.Drawing.Color` that you store as class/member variable(shared or as instance-variable).